# or where group on codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have a code like this in codeigniter

```
foreach ($where as $k=>$v){
    foreach ($v as $val){
        $this->db->or_where($k, $val);  
    }                   
}
```

but, i want 'or where group' like

```
select * from table where id = '1' and (category = 'tekno' OR category ='biologi');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your code actually give you, versus what you want it to give you?

Answer (score 3):

I've often resorted to building queries manually if more complicated grouping of where clauses is needed.

```
$or_where = "";
foreach ($where as $k => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $val) {
        $or_where .= "OR category = '$val' ";
    }                   
}
```

You can then add to your existing Active Record query:

```
$this->db->where($or_where);
```

OR

```
$this->db->or_where($or_where);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add more where like this:

```
$this->db->where('id', 1);
$this->db->where('(category', 'tekno');
$this->db->or_where('category', 'biologi');
$this->db->where('1=1)');
```